# Oxidative phosphorylation analogue

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, biochemistry, chemical-biology, electricity

Does the salt bridge in galvanic cells resemble the ATP pump in the inner mitochondrial membrane? And if yes than did someone use this pH difference in harvesting this energy?